# cleveref referencing figures from current and external documents

Tags: cleveref, xr

Here is the setup:
In doc2.tex, I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{figure there}
\label{fig:there}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And in doc1.tex I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\externaldocument[otherdoc-]{doc2}

\begin{document}


\cref{fig:here,otherdoc-fig:there} \cref{fig:here} \cref{otherdoc-fig:there}

\newpage

\begin{figure}

\caption{figure doc1}
\label{fig:here}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, the command `\cref{fig:here,otherdoc-fig:there}` is not referencing both figures as I was expecting. I am getting as output:

```
fig. 1 fig. 1 fig. 1
```

but I was expecting:

```
figs. 1 and 1 fig. 1 fig. 1
```

Please let me know if you know how to correct this, or why `cref` is failing here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use `zref` and `zref-clever`, the latter takes care not to compress labels coming from different documents, even if they have the same printed representation. But indeed you must be cautious in combining references from different documents in such a framework, since it may well confuse the reader.

doc1.tex:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\zexternaldocument[otherdoc-]{doc2}

\begin{document}

\zcref{fig:here,otherdoc-fig:there}

\zcref{fig:here}

\zcref{otherdoc-fig:there}

\newpage

\begin{figure}

\caption{figure doc1}
\zlabel{fig:here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

doc2.tex:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{figure there}
\zlabel{fig:there}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found one way of avoiding the problem is adding the following line in the preambule of doc2.tex:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
```

Then I get as output:

```
figs. S1 and 1 fig. 1 fig. S1
```

So probably when cleveref sees figures with the same label, it believes it is the same figure, although it is coming from different documents.

It is not an ideal solution, but better than nothing. Maybe a bug of cleveref?